# ElasticSearch Filter Multiple Fields Required

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-php

I have this query (via PHP client) for ElasticSearch 6.2:

```
[
    "query"=> [
        "bool" => [
            "filter" => [
                "term" => [ "row.name" => $name ],
                "term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "size" => "10"
]
```

It works if I use just one search for either `row.name` or `row.origin`, but with both it works like an OR and returns all results. How can I filter to only return documents that are an exact match for `row.name` AND `row.origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the right way, but I'm guessing that you missed parenthesis.

Instead of:

```
[
    "query"=> [
        "bool" => [
            "filter" => [
                "term" => [ "row.name" => $name ],
                "term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "size" => "10"
]
```

You should have:

```
[
    "query"=> [
        "bool" => [
            "filter" => [
                ["term" => [ "row.name" => $name ]],
                ["term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "size" => "10"
]
```

In your case you created a map with two same (`term`) keys:

```
[
  "term" => [ "row.name" => $name ],
  "term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]
]
```

So the second `term` overrode the first one and in reality, you sent:

```
[
  "term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]
]
```

To send multiple `term` filters you need so they will be treated as a list:

```
[
  ["term" => [ "row.name" => $name ]],
  ["term" => [ "row.origin" => $origin ]]
]
```